# Responsive media query not working for browser re size on pc

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am making a responsive design for my website.

I have made two separate css files for this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media = "screen and (min-device-width: 500px) and (max-device-width: 1500px)" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 500px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

Its working fine when seen through any phone. But when I resize my browser on my pc the stylesheet does not change.

I want both things to happen. Stylesheets should change in both cases - if the device width is changed or if browser window is resized.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `min`/`max-device-width`, use `min`/`max-width`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media = "screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1500px)" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 500px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

Now the stylesheet depends on the width of the viewport, instead of the width of the device. Presumably the width of the viewport on a mobile device is the same as the device width, so this kills two birds with one stone.

Comment: I did this initially but then it was not working for phones. mobile.css was being ignored

Comment: @RoopaliBansal `500px` seems like a pretty large value to me. Try using `300px` as the mobile/desktop boundary instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put all of your CSS-Code in one File:

```
@media (min-width: 501px)  {
  //put your desktop styles here
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  //put your phone design here
}
```

Comment: That would be a bad idea from a maintainability perspective.

Comment: And good idea for performance, because this practice will help you reduce number of http request.